# Jquery isn't recognized in simple html5 web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have been searching whole afternoon for a solution, but I didn't found it. I am writing a HTML5 webpage, using jquery and css. I'm trying to implement very simple drop down menu (I found tutorial [here](http://wabism.com/jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial/)) but it does not work for me. I have copy paste this code from this article to a local html file and open it in browser and it works great, just as I want to implement menu, but when I try to implement the same code in my webpage it doesn't work.

I get in my console log displayed two errors:
(SyntaxError: function statement requires a name - jquery.js: row 2072) and then after this error i get
(ReferenceError: $ is not defined - index.html row 15, where the $ sign occurs).

I have been searching a lot, but I didn't found anything usefull which might help me. I have also checked number of times if I might have problem in jquery script declaration but It's ok. I don't have any idea why this simple code don't work in my application but in external code it works just fine. I have also try to insert language and text type on script tag, but I didn't work, neither if I leave script tag empty. I use latest Mozilla Firefox browser.

Here is my application code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skin/default.css">

    <script src="script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/picture.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/ApplicationController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $("body").ready(function() {
            $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
                $(this).find(".sub_navigation").slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onApplicationLoad()">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="http://www.notreallink.fail/" target="_blank"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"  alt="Logo" width="200" height="38" /></a>
        <div id="verticalHeaderLine"></div>

        <div id="headerMenu">            
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li class="dropdown"> <button id="Login" class="button" title="Edit Login">Login</button>
                    <ul class="sub_navigation">
                        <li><button id="test" class="button" title="Edit Test">Test</button></li>
                        <li><button id="test1" class="button" title="Edit Test">Test 1</button></li>
                        <li><button id="test2" class="button" title="Edit Test">Test 2</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is a css related to menu:

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    min-width:200px;
}

ul#navigation {
    float:left;
}

ul#navigation li {
    float:left;
    min-width:200px;
}

ul.sub_navigation {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

ul.sub_navigation li {
    clear:both;
}
```

I would be very happy if someone know what do I do wrong and if he could be so kind and tolk me what do I do wrong.

Regards,
Dahakka

Comment: why dont you just include jquery from google `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: The code I see here is exactly the same as in the demo's page. So first of all do you have the local copy of the jQuery file in your system or wherever

Comment: Treid just now what you suggest, but it didn't work also. Client log gives me ReferenceError displayed :( EDIT: Yes, I have local copy of jquery library(1.9.1) which was in script folder and also in folder where index in spresented, but notthing from this worked

Answer (score 4):

`$("body").ready(function() {` should be `$(document).ready(function() {`
It's usually better to let Google host jQuery for you. See http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/ for a full explanation. Replace your reference to jQuery with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Also, at the end of your document, you have `<body><html>` instead of `</body></html>`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replay. I have already tried this, but it didn't work neither :(

Comment: Ya, clearly jquery is not being loaded onto the page, hence `$` being undefined

Comment: The contents of your other js files may be interfering. Try removing those and see if the jQuery works then.

Comment: Hi, I have remove all other js files from index.html file, but problem is still the same as before, but I have successfully get displayed error, that there are mising functions which were declared in removed js files.

Comment: At the end of your document, you have `<body><html>` instead of `</body></html>`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. This is my mistake when I have copy code to stackoverflow and forgot to include slash. I repair it, but still experiencing the same issue :(

Comment: If you still see that `jQuery` or `$` is not defined, then you're still not including jQuery in your page. Are you using the link to Google that's in my post?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your link. I have copy link before, but It didn't work, because i didn't notice, that http is missing in your link. I add not http and page now works just fine with your help! Thanks a lot Mooseman! But I still don't understand why I can't read my local jquery file but I have included it in folder and I am sure, that I have proper paths to it :(

Comment: What version of jQuery is your local file. Please mark my post as 'best answer' for future users.

Comment: I have already mark it for best answer, you deserve it. I use jquery-1.9.1.js not min js. Maybe this might be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think jquery is not being found. try adding this to your `<head></head>`.

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This is the google hosted jquery. If you have internet access it should at least solve your first problem

Comment: Already tries this a few minutes ago, but it didn't work. Same as before.

Comment: hmm. Ya, try stripping your other JS files. Side note you should always close a link tag: `<link attributes="" />`

Comment: I don't understand you very well what do you want to say?

Comment: A link tag should look have a `/` at the end to close it

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I tries that also with a </script> tag and with /> but noone of them worked for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
            $(this).find(".sub_navigation").slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Try this to see if there is a conflict or just jQuery isn't loaded at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. It still don't work. Console log shows me ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined :(